# FrameworkVersion in prebuild event VS2010 WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, environment-variables

I'm trying to start msbuild in prebuild event like this

```
$(FrameworkDir)$(FrameworkVersion)\msbuild /t:updateuid $(ProjectPath)
```

But I see that $(FrameworkVersion) gives v2.0.50727.
If I start the VS2010 command line prompt $(FrameworkVersion) gives v4.0.30319.

Why points this environment variable to an old version when in prebuild event?

Is there something wrong with my WPF project (my target framework is 4)?

Comment: are you sure that the target framework of the project that you are building is 4.0?

Comment: Yes, .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remembered having a similar problem. Try the following command instead:

```
$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild /t:updateuid $(ProjectPath)
```

Comment: Thank you, now the tools work. But it's still calling v2.050727. Do you know why? Is this ok?

Comment: What version of VS did you use to create your project? Make sure that your project uses the correct tools version. Open your `.csproj` with a text editor and make sure it starts with `<Project ToolsVersion="4.0">`

Comment: I created the project with VS2010, ToolVersion is 4.0.